# Where to find Android Development Homework Problems

Tags: android, wiki

Ok so I am starting off with android development and I have found a bunch of useful tutorials so I am set there.  What I am looking for is a resource that provides homework style problems to do and has the answers downloadable so I can check my solution against the "official" solution.

So for example instead of the notepad tutorial it would be: "Build an application that you can create, edit, delete notes, ...etc.".  Ideally the "official" solution would have some explanation as to why they built it the way they did. (so a tutorial at the tail end)

Anyone know of any resources that provide their tutorials in this format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's one:  build me an app that allows the user to make, modify, and store notes. The 'official' answer is the Notepad app in the 9th level of the api.  (Note that this is different from the notepad tutorial).

The point is that asking questions is easy, the harder part is actually making a program that does the job.  And @Roflecoptr is right, at this level it can be implemented very differently.  But if you want that mindset, you can write your own 'homework' easily.  Just think up a few things you want that are simple, build it, does it do what you want well?  Then you pass.

Comment: Thanks for the homework problem going to start working on it now.  The main reason for a third party source for the homework problem is to get past the "It works" mentality and make sure my implementation of a solution follows best practices, remains responsive as part of a larger application, ..etc.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Well, I've yet to see many 'best practices' sources for android, but there are some on the dev site, for example this: http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=c4znvD-7VDA and this: http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=N6YdwzAvwOA

Comment: +1 for the links.  Will wait a day or so to see if anyone knows of a homework style tutorial site before accepting as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Despite for very trivial problems I dont think this is possible, because there are way to much possible implementation possibilites so that you can't compare your solution to the "official" solution.

But why do you need something like that? If you want to learn to program on Android, you can just follow some tutorials you've already found and then modify them, adapt them to your needs. When you get more used to the development of Android apps you can just get some ideas on tutorials/android development sites and then implement your own solution. There is plenty of help available here on SO and on other development sites, which will help you if you really get stuck.

Comment: I agree that there is plenty of help available if I get stuck.  The reason I would like some homework problems instead of just a normal tutorial is I tend to learn better if I have a problem to solve (even if it is a simple one).  These homework problems would help me sort out some of my deficiencies before moving on to a project that has a deadline and potentially destined for public consumption.  Tutorials while helpful walk me through the solution rather than giving me an opportunity to try to work out the solution first.

Comment: Building "real" applications - even when discarded when complete - are much better means of learning a platform and it's API than just tutorials. Coming up with ideas for real projects that are large enough in scope to be useful, but small enough to be practical is difficult. Homework style projects fit this profile nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You could always go to the Android Samples page, and without looking at their implementations, do your own and compare. The samples page is here:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/index.html